# Insert new increment value

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT into products (basket_number)
  (SELECT (MAX(basket_number) + 1) FROM products WHERE user_id = 9);
```

When I do the statement above it will correctly add a new row with the basket_number updated. But when trying any way to also insert the user_id it will not work. For example below:

```
INSERT into products (user_id,basket_number)
 (9, (SELECT (MAX(basket_number) + 1) FROM products WHERE user_id = 9));
```

Im not sure what I am required to do to fix this issue.

Comment: In a well-structured database, it seems unlikely that this is something you would want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you certainly can make the syntax work here:

```
INSERT into products (user_id, basket_number)
SELECT 9, MAX(basket_number) + 1
FROM products
WHERE user_id = 9;
```

But typically if you want an auto incrementing sequence in your table, you should just make one of the columns (usually the primary key) an auto increment column.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  an INSERT / SELECT this way

```
  INSERT into products (user_id,basket_number)
  select user_id, (MAX(basket_number) + 1
  from products 
  where user_id  = 9
  group by  user_id
```

Comment: I have never used the group by before what's this used for?

Comment: group by is for aggreated  result that return more than a row ..  you can obtain for each grouped  by key the related  aggregated  result  .. if you want insert several  values one for different user_id in one shot you need  group by otherwise you have an error